# Insert Binary Value with execute + ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, binary

I need to perform a PostgreSQL [upsert](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html) query with ActiveRecord:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO call_records (created_at, updated_at, number_tag, tag, raw_data)
  VALUES (current_timestamp, current_timestamp, 123, 'R', BINARY_VALUE)
  ON CONFLICT (number_tag) DO
  UPDATE SET tag = 'L' WHERE call_records.tag='L'"
```

The column `raw_data` contains the binary value `BINARY_VALUE` upon trying to store the binary value by running the following command:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(%Q{#{sql}})
```

It returns the following error:

```
ArgumentError: string contains null byte
```

The binary string look like this:

```
"\x00\x00\x00\x95\x01\x00\x00\x02"
```

How do I store this? I also tried:

```
value = "\x00\x00\x00\x95\x01\x00\x00\x02".unpack('H*')[0]
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote("\\x#{value}")
```

But it does not work. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: What versions of Rails and Ruby are you using? (As a side note, don't do this: `...execute(%Q{#{sql}})`. `sql` is already a string. Just do this: `...execute(sql)`.)

Answer (score -1):

Found it the answer to the question is

`raw_bytea` method in rails `active_record` connection.